# Module var behavior

Tags: python

I am trying to use a module `mod_a.py` to store some app global information (in a webapp environment), but I notice on page reloads, the imported module's global vars aren't re-initialized, i.e. `q = []`, and so `q` accumulates items instead of being reset every HTTP request cycle.

This behaviour seems odds. I am using my own dead basic framework (for learning) served thru gunicorn as a wsgi app.  NOTE: If I modify `mod_a.py` then `q` is reset as expected, leading me to a caching issue of some sort.

**mod_a.py**

```
q = []
def add(item):
    global q
    q.append(item)
```

**mod_b.py**

```
import mod_a as a

a.add('newitem')

print(a.q)
```

Comment: @pat it is running as a standard wsgi app in gunicorn

Comment: I don't know `gunicorn` at all, but I'm pretty sure that WSGI is pretty flexible on whether or not servers keep the same interpreter running for many requests or if they shut down between them. Your code probably shouldn't be using any global state like that. (Note that your `global` statement is completely unnecessary, since you're not rebinding `q` in `add`, just mutating it in place.)

Comment: Web servers should be stateless. You need a proper database

Comment: @cricket_007, what if this was module was used to store http request info? Would that not be a valid use case?

Comment: Your list will still be lost on following requests until you persist it to disk or manage to find any way to track a session without cookies

Comment: @cricket_007, right, it only carries info for the current request, like POST, GET vars.

Comment: My point is that modules don't magically maintain state by being in a separate file. You'll at the very least need `pickle` to serialize your list, then deserialize, append, reserialize

Comment: @Blckknght Ok, I think I have a handle on what is happening.  The server isn't tearing down the global environment at every request as it is using the same long-lived interpreter session(s) to service new requests.  If I wanted to a module to store request data, accessible to other modules, I would need another approach, maybe creating a Request obj at the wsgi level passed into the app.